# Given a point $P$, the point $(-2, 4, 7)$ is $\frac13$ of the way between $P$ and another point $Q$. Find $Q$

Tags: vectors

Let $P$ be the point $(3, -4, -6)$. Suppose that the point $P_{0}(-2, 4, 7)$ is  $\frac{1}{3}$  of the way from $P$ to $Q$.

Find the point $Q$.

I tried multiplying $P_{0}$ by $3$ and adding it to $P$, but it wasn't right.

Comment: The section formula

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry. I don't really know how stackexchange works. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac23P+\frac13Q=(-2,4,7)\implies Q=3(-2,4,7)-2P
$$
Therefore,
$$
Q=(-6,12,21)-(6,-8,-12)=(-12,20,33)
$$

Answer (score 2):

$P-P_0 = \frac{1}{3}(P-Q)$ since the point $P_0$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ of the way from $P$ to $Q$.

So $(3,-4,-6)-(-2,4,7)=(5,-8,-13)=\frac{1}{3}(P-Q)$$\implies$
$-3\cdot(5,-8,-13)+P=Q$

$Q=(-15,24,39)+(3,-4,-6)= (-12,20,33)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q$ be $(x,y,z)$.

Then, as $P_0$ divides $PQ$ internally in the ratio $1:2$, using the section formula for $x$,

$$-2=\frac{(1)x+(2)(3)}{1+2}\Rightarrow x=-12$$

Similarly, using for $y,z$, we get,
$$Q\equiv (-12,20,33)$$.

Answer (score 0):

let $Q(a, b, c)$ then the coordinates of the point $P_0(-2, 4, 7)$ internally dividing the line $PQ$ in a ratio $1:2$ is given by section formula,  $$(-2, 4, 7)\equiv \left(\frac{1\cdot a+2\cdot 3}{1+2}, \frac{1\cdot b+2\cdot (-4)}{1+2}, \frac{1\cdot c+2\cdot (-6)}{1+2} \right)$$
$$(-2, 4, 7)\equiv \left(\frac{a+6}{3}, \frac{b-8}{3}, \frac{c-12}{3} \right)$$
comparing the corresponding coordinates, one should get
$$\frac{a+6}{3}=-2, \ \frac{b-8}{3}=4, \ \frac{c-12}{3}=7$$
or $$a=-12, \ b=20, \ c=33$$
hence, the coordinates of the point $Q$ are $\color{red}{(-12, 20, 33)}$